# How to add vertical spacing between definitions

Tags: spacing, amsmath, theorems

I'm trying to add vertical space between definitions, theorems, etc. For example, if set up something like:

```
\begin{definition}

blah blah blah

\end{definition}

%%%should be space here but there's not

\begin{theorem}

blah blah blah

\end{theorem}
```

There is almost no vertical room after my definition and before my new theorem. How do I fix this?

Comment: `\vspace*{2cm}` should work, where you can replace `2cm` to any length.

Answer (score 2):

Have you defined the Theorem and Definition correctly?  When I use the following code, there is space between the lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theory of Blahblah}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition of Blah}
\begin{document}
    \begin{definition}
        blah blah blah
    \end{definition}
%%%should be space here but there's not
    \begin{theorem}
        blah blah blah
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

If this is insufficient space for you, there are several ways you can 'brute force' vertical space between lines.  Adding a \smallskip between the lines in the text may be what you are looking for.

If you consistently need more space after every Theorem or Definition, you can try redefining the environment.  However, I will omit that at this time.  Fooling around with a strict environment such as amsmath can displease some of your audience.

Comment: Part of my preamble looks like: 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheoremstyle{definition}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{note}{Note}

Comment: I'll just keep using my shortcut "\vs" for "\vspace{8ex}". Thank you.